# undefined behavior in shared lib using libpthread, but not having it in ELF as dependency

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, pthreads, gold-linker

When linked "properly" (explained further), both function calls below block indefinitely on pthread calls implementing `cv.notify_one` and `cv.wait_for`:

```
// let's call it odr.cpp, which forms libodr.so

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool ready = false;

void Notify() {
  std::chrono::milliseconds(100);
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
  ready = true;
  cv.notify_one();
}

void Get() {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
  cv.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
}
```

when shared library above is used in following application:

```
// let's call it test.cpp, which forms a.out

int main() {
  std::thread thr([&]() {
    std::cout << "Notify\n";
    Notify();
  });

  std::cout << "Before Get\n";
  Get();
  std::cout << "After Get\n";

  thr.join();
}
```

Problem reproduces only when linking `libodr.so`:

- with g++
- with gold linker
- providing `-lpthread` as dependency

with following versions of relevant tools:

- `Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia`
- `binutils    2.26.1-1ubuntu1~16.04.6`
- `g++         4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1`
- `libc6:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu10`

so that we end up with:

- `__pthread_key_create` defined as WEAK symbol in PLT
- no `libpthread.so` as dependency in ELF

as shown here:

```
$ g++ -fPIC -shared -o build/libodr.so build/odr.cpp.o -fuse-ld=gold -lpthread && readelf -d build/libodr.so | grep Shared && readelf -Ws build/libodr.so | grep -m1 __pthread_key_create
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
    10: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __pthread_key_create
```

On the other hand, with any of the following we experience no bug:

- clang++
- bfd linker
- no explicit `-lpthread`
- `-lpthread` but with `-Wl,--no-as-needed`

note: this time we have either:

- `NOTYPE` and no `libpthread.so` dependency
- `WEAK` and `libpthread.so` dependency

as shown here:

```
$ clang++ -fPIC -shared -o build/libodr.so build/odr.cpp.o -fuse-ld=gold -lpthread && readelf -d build/libodr.so | grep Shared && readelf -Ws build/libodr.so | grep -m1 __pthread_key_create && ./a.out 
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
    24: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __pthread_key_create@GLIBC_2.2.5 (7)

$ g++ -fPIC -shared -o build/libodr.so build/odr.cpp.o -fuse-ld=bfd -lpthread && readelf -d build/libodr.so | grep Shared && readelf -Ws build/libodr.so | grep -m1 __pthread_key_create && ./a.out 
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
    14: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __pthread_key_create

$ g++ -fPIC -shared -o build/libodr.so build/odr.cpp.o -fuse-ld=gold && readelf -d build/libodr.so | grep Shared && readelf -Ws build/libodr.so | grep -m1 __pthread_key_create && ./a.out  0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
    18: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __pthread_key_create

$ g++ -fPIC -shared -o build/libodr.so build/odr.cpp.o -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--no-as-needed -lpthread && readelf -d build/libodr.so | grep Shared && readelf -Ws build/libodr.so | grep -m1 __pthread_key_create && ./a.out 
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
    10: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __pthread_key_create@GLIBC_2.2.5 (4)
```

Complete example to compile/run can be found here: https://github.com/aurzenligl/study/tree/master/cpp-pthread

What breaks shlib using pthread when `__pthread_key_create` is `WEAK` and no `libpthread.so` dependency in ELF can be found? Does the dynamic linker take the pthread symbols from `libc.so` (stubs) instead of `libpthread.so`?

Comment: I think you might be using the term *"undefined behavior"* incorrectly. It usually refers to violations of C-family rules, not undefined symbols and references.

Comment: The problem happens at run-time, when (after improper initialization of some static data?) pthread calls behave in an "undefined" manner. It's not merely a linking issue - then you couldn't link statically or dynamically due to missing symbols. It's a bit more contrived.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot happening here: differences between gcc and clang, differences between gnu ld and gold, the `--as-needed` linker flag, two different failure modes, and maybe even some timing issues.

Let's start with how to link a program using POSIX threads.

The compiler's `-pthread` flag is all you should need. It's a compiler flag, so you should use it both when compiling code that uses threads and when linking the final executable. When you use `-pthread` on the link step, the compiler will provide the `-lpthread` flag automatically, and in the right place in the link line.

Typically, you would only use it when linking the final executable, and not when linking a shared library. If you simply want to make your library thread safe, but don't want to force every program that uses your library to link with pthreads, you'd want to use a runtime check to see if the pthreads library is loaded, and call the pthread APIs only if it is. On Linux, this is typically done by checking a "canary" -- for example, make a weak reference to an arbitrary symbol like `__pthread_key_create`, which will only be defined if the library is loaded, and will have the value 0 if the program was linked without it.

In your case, however, your library `libodr.so` pretty much depends on threads, so it's reasonable to link it with the `-pthread` flag.

That brings us to the first failure mode: if you use g++ and gold for both link steps, the program throws `std::system_error` and says you need to enable multithreading. This is due to the `--as-needed` flag. GCC passes `--as-needed` to the linker by default, while clang (apparently) does not. With `--as-needed`, the linker will only record library dependencies that resolve a strong reference. Since all the references to pthread APIs are weak, none of them are sufficient to tell the linker that libpthread.so should be added to the dependency list (via a `DT_NEEDED` entry in the dynamic table). Changing to clang or adding a `-Wl,--no-as-needed` flag solves this problem, and the program will load the pthread library.

But, wait, why don't you need to do this when using the Gnu linker? It uses the same rule: only a strong reference causes the library to be recorded as a dependency. The difference is that Gnu ld also considers references from other shared libraries, while gold only considers references from regular object files. It turns out that the pthread library provides overriding definitions of several libc symbols, and there are strong references from `libstdc++.so` to some of those symbols (e.g., `write`). Those strong references are enough to get Gnu ld to record `libpthread.so` as a dependency. This is more of an accident than design; I don't think changing gold to consider references from other shared libraries would actually be a robust fix. I think the proper solution is for GCC to put `--no-as-needed` in front of the `-lpthread` flag when you use `-pthread`.

This begs the question of why this issue doesn't come up all the time when using POSIX threads and the gold linker. But this is a small test program; a larger program is almost certain to contain strong references to some of those libc symbols that `libpthread.so` overrides.

Now let's look at the second failure mode, where both `Notify()` and `Get()` block indefinitely if you link `libodr.so` with g++, gold and `-lpthread`.

In `Notify()`, you're holding the lock through the end of the function, while you call `cv.notify_one()`. You really only need to hold the lock to set the ready flag; if we change it so that we release the lock before that, then the thread calling `Get()` will timeout after 300 ms, and does not block. So it's really the call to `notify_one()` that's blocking, and the program is deadlocking because `Get()` is waiting on that same lock.

So why does it block only when `__pthread_key_create` is `FUNC` instead of `NOTYPE`? I think the type of the symbol is a red herring, and that the real problem is caused by the fact that gold doesn't record the symbol versions for references resolved by a library that isn't added as a needed library. The implementation of `wait_for` calls `pthread_cond_timedwait`, which has two versions in both `libpthread` and `libc`. It's possible that the loader is binding the reference to the wrong version, causing a deadlock by failing to unlock the mutex. I made a temporary patch to gold to record those versions, and that made the program work. Unfortunately, that's not a solution, as that patch can cause ld.so to crash under other circumstances.

I tried changing `cv.wait_for(...)` to `cv.wait(lock, []{ return ready; })`, and the program runs perfectly in all scenarios, which further suggests that the problem is with `pthread_cond_timedwait`.

The bottom line is that adding the `--no-as-needed` flag will fix the problem for this very small test case. Anything larger is likely to work without the extra flag, as you'll be increasing the odds of making a strong reference to a symbol in `libpthread`. (For example, adding a call to `std::this_thread::sleep_for` *anywhere* in `odr.cpp` adds a strong reference to `nanosleep`, which puts `libpthread` in the needed list.)

**Update:** I've verified that the failing program is linking to the wrong version of `pthread_cond_timedwait`. For glibc 2.3.2, the `pthread_cond_t` type was changed, and the old versions of the APIs that use the type were changed to dynamically allocate a new (bigger) structure and store a pointer to it in the original type. So now, if the consuming thread reaches `cv.wait_for` before the producing thread reaches `cv.notify_one`, the implementation of `cv.wait_for` calls the old version of `pthread_cond_timedwait`, which initializes what it thinks is an old `pthread_cond_t` in `cv` with a pointer to a new `pthread_cond_t`. After that, when the other thread reaches `cv.notify_one`, its implementation assumes that `cv` contains a new-style `pthread_cond_t` rather than a pointer to one, so it calls `pthread_mutex_lock` with the pointer to the new `pthread_cond_t` instead of the pointer to the mutex. It locks that would-be mutex, but it never gets unlocked because the other thread unlocks the real mutex.

Comment: The same program doesn't deadlock if clang/bfd-linker/no-as-needed is used, moreover `notify_one` may not block (btw. calling `notify_one` while under cv's lock is legal). There are two threads involved and both ultimately progress, regardless of which holds the lock first. So - I suppose it's not an issue with ill-formed C++ program.

`wait_for` uses a different pthread symbol than `wait`, which might influence linking mechanism in some way. After all - the problem doesn't happen when `wait` is used, and it still happens when `wait_for` with predicate is used.

Comment: I didn't say it was illegal to call `notify_one` with the lock -- I said it was unnecessary. (If you're still holding the lock, the other thread will wake up, but then immediately block again when it tries to lock the mutex again.) Releasing the lock earlier shows that it's the `notify_one` that's blocking.

Comment: A little further digging suggests that the difference in behavior is caused by missing versions on the calls to `pthread_mutex_lock/unlock` and `pthread_cond_timedwait`. When you add -lpthread on the link line, but it doesn't get added as a needed library, gold does not record the version information. `pthread_cond_timedwait` in particular is suspicious, as both libpthread and libc contain two versions of it. I wonder whether it's somehow binding to the wrong one, but any attempt at figuring that out makes the problem go away.

Comment: I just read the `Update`. Good finding! Which tool would be the cause of such behavior - linker, since it doesn't record the new version of `pthread_cond_timedwait` symbol in ELF?

Comment: I'll be changing gold so that it picks up the version info for those symbols from libc when libpthread turns out to be not needed. I'm also thinking of filing a bug report against GCC to add --no-as-needed for -lpthread.

Comment: I've committed a patch to gold; the fix will be in the upcoming binutils 2.31 release.